# Finding colors that have not been assigned to a given user

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

Goal: make this code as efficient as possible.

Given a finite dataset (Colors - this isn't Crayola here :D) how do I know what colors are **not** assigned to a given user?

Additional requirement - the final result should output a single column of comma-delimited colors. Spaces do not matter, but it'd be nice.

This current code chokes after 5,000 records and when this scales it will easily surpass 500,000.

```
USE master
GO

--======================================================================
-- Data Setup.
--======================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employees') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Employees
END

CREATE TABLE #Employees(
    ID INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,FavoriteColor VARCHAR(MAX)
)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Colors') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Colors
END

CREATE TABLE #Colors( Color VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Blue');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Green');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Red');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Yellow');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Orange');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('White');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Black');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Cyan');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Magenta');
INSERT INTO #Colors VALUES('Brown');

INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(1, 'Bob', 'Blue');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(1, 'Bob', 'Green');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(1, 'Bob', 'Red');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(1, 'Bob', 'Yellow');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(2, 'Kate', 'White');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(3, 'Ben', 'Yellow');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(3, 'Ben', 'Magenta');
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES(3, 'Ben', 'Cyan');

--======================================================================
--Select the total number of favorite colors for each employee. - Done
--======================================================================
SELECT ID, Name, COUNT(FavoriteColor) AS FavoriteColorCount
FROM #Employees
GROUP BY ID, Name

--======================================================================
--Select each employee's favorite colors. - Done
--======================================================================
SELECT ID, Name, COUNT(FavoriteColor) AS FavoriteColorCount
,STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), x.FavoriteColor)
                FROM #Employees x
               WHERE     E.ID = x.ID AND E.Name = X.Name
            GROUP BY x.FavoriteColor FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') AS FavoriteColorsList   
FROM #Employees E
GROUP BY ID, Name

--======================================================================
--Select colors not in the favorite employee's list. - Having issues
--======================================================================
SELECT ID, Name, COUNT(FavoriteColor) AS FavoriteColorCount
,STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), x.FavoriteColor)
                FROM #Employees x
               WHERE     E.ID = x.ID AND E.Name = X.Name
            GROUP BY x.FavoriteColor FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') AS FavoriteColorsList   
, '' AS ExcludedColorsList  --How do I get this value?
FROM #Employees E
GROUP BY ID, Name

--======================================================================
--CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION - very slow, having performance problems.
--======================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Exploded') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Exploded
END

--Explode the dataset and isolate all records not included in the users selection.
SELECT DISTINCT 
     E.ID
    ,E.Name
    ,C.Color
INTO #Exploded
FROM #Employees E
CROSS JOIN #Colors C
EXCEPT 
SELECT 
     E.ID
    ,E.Name
    ,E.FavoriteColor
FROM #Employees E

SELECT DISTINCT Ex.ID, Ex.Name
,STUFF((
         select ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T1.Color)
        from #Exploded T1
        where   T1.ID       = Ex.ID
            AND T1.Name = Ex.Name

        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS MissingColorList

FROM #Exploded Ex
INNER JOIN #Employees EMP ON 
    Ex.ID = Emp.ID
    AND Ex.Name = EMP.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should normalize your data. It is N-M relationship and you should use `junction table`:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                       Name VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE Colors(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
                    Color VARCHAR(100),
                    UNIQUE(Color));

CREATE TABLE EmployeesColors(EmployeeID INT REFERENCES Employees(ID),
                             ColorId INT REFERENCES Colors(ID),
                             PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID, ColorID));
```

Then your query could be simplified to:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT sub.EmpId, sub.Name, sub.ColorID, sub.Color
  FROM (SELECT EmpId = e.ID, e.Name, ColorId = c.ID, c.Color
        FROM #Employees e
        CROSS JOIN #Colors c) AS sub
  LEFT JOIN #EmployeesColors ec
    ON sub.EmpId = ec.EmployeeID
   AND sub.ColorID = ec.ColorID
  WHERE ec.EmployeeID IS NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID = EmpId, Name
      ,MissingColors = STUFF((SELECT ',' + T2.Color      
                              FROM cte T2
                              WHERE T1.EmpId = T2.EmpId  
                              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM cte T1
--ORDER BY ID;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434233)**</kbd>

Comment: On the right track. This is better than what I have originally, however. This tends to choke on more than 150 colors. [Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434854/colors-bottleneck-with-lots-of-colors)